# Insertion sort using vectors, not working

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, insertion-sort

Im trying to create an insertion sort algorithm using vectors, but instead of parsing the elements from the start of the array (vector here), i tried doing it from the end. The code does nothing but sort the element for the first time, and delete the first element of my vector. I want to know what correction to my code can I make for this to work.
Basic procedure:

1. Start by element towards last (second last element)
2. Insert it in correct position in the 'sorted' subarray (vector) after it
3. Delete it from its initial position
4. Continue with algorithm, traversing backwards until vector's beginning

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void isort(vector <T> &ar){
    //start from second last element upto first element
    for(auto i = ar.end()-2; i >= ar.begin(); i--){
        //iterator pointing towards element next to insertion element
        auto j = i + 1;
        //traverse and increase the pointer until condition met
        while(j != ar.end() && *i < *j) j++;
        //insert the insertion element at final position of the pointer
        ar.insert(j,*i);
        //erase the original element
        ar.erase(i);
    }
}
template <class T>
void display(vector <T> &ar){
    for(auto i = ar.begin(); i != ar.end(); i++){
        cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
    vector <int> X {6,1,7,1,3,2,6723,4,1,6};
    display <int>(X);
    isort <int>(X);
    display <int>(X);
}
```

Expected output:

```
6 1 7 1 3 2 6723 4 1 6 
1 1 1 2 3 4 6 6 7 6723
```

Output attained:

```
6 1 7 1 3 2 6723 4 1 6 
1 7 1 3 2 6723 4 1 6 1
```

Comment: *I want to know what correction to my code can I make for this to work* -- [What is a debugger ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Insertion into a vector can invalidate all existing iterators if it has to increase its capacity.

Comment: `i >= ar.begin()` is always `true` if `i` is a valid iterator for `ar`. If it isn't a valid iterator for `ar` then the comparison is not allowed. You cannot decrement an iterator to an element for which this condition becomes false. `ar.begin() - 1` is Undeifned Behavior.

Comment: [Look at the alternative to your code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24650626/how-to-implement-classic-sorting-algorithms-in-modern-c).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux but the loop runs finitely and terminates when `i` becomes less than `ar.begin()`. But for some reason with each itertion, no other part of the for loop is being executed, just `i` decreasing and finally the last `ar.erase(i)` is being executed, hence eliminating the first element

Comment: The most important thing @François Andrieux said, "_Insertion into a vector can invalidate all existing iterators_". And you are calling `ar.insert(...)`. And keeping your old iterators around without updating them.

Comment: @Mamba Valid `i` can *never* become less than `ar.begin()`. An attempt to make it less than `ar.begin()` is undefined behaviour.

Comment: @lakeweb ahh i see i see, thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @Mamba The loop only looks like it works when you tried it. Different build configurations or different architectures could change that. For example the compiler might in theory optimize the condition to just `true` because it is equivalent and faster. Or, you might change the container from `vector` to something else later. And then the comparison or decrement operation might crash or cause other undesired behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Ahh okay okaay, i have rectified that mistake in my code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my implementation of Insertion reverse algo.

```
template <class T>
void isort(vector <T> &ar){
    if(ar.size() < 2)
        return;
    //start from second last element upto first element
    for(auto i = ar.end()-2; i >= ar.begin(); i--){

        auto j = i;
        //swap values until condition met
        while((j + 1) != ar.end() && *(j + 1) < *j) {
            //swap values
            auto tmp = *j;
            *j = *(j + 1);
            *(j + 1) = tmp;
            ++j;
        }
    }
}
```

The difference here it swaps the two values instead of insert/erase.

```
while(j != ar.end() && *i < *j) j++;
//insert the insertion element at final position of the pointer
ar.insert(j,*i);
//erase the original element
ar.erase(i);
```

Comment: okay, thank you. i thought of making it using inert and erase just to try it out, but that apparently changes the iterators themselves, so swapping is a must

Comment: Tactical note: Save some code and use `std::swap`.

Comment: `for(auto i = ar.end()-2; i >= ar.begin(); i--)` invokes undefined behaviour. You can't decrement `ar.begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

About your way, so I modified a bit your code according to your solution, so it works now.
The performance might be even worse than swapping, just because vector shifts elements after insert/erase.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
void isort(vector <T>& ar) {
    if (ar.size() < 2)
        return;

    //start from second last element upto first element
    auto i = ar.end() - 2;
    do
    {
        //iterator pointing towards element next to insertion element
        auto j = i + 1;
        //traverse and increase the pointer until condition met
        while (j != ar.end() && *i > *j) ++j;
        //insert the insertion element at final position of the pointer

        if (*(j - 1) < *i && (j - 1) != i) {
            ar.insert(j, *i);
            i = ar.erase(i);
        }

        if (i == ar.begin())
            break;
        --i;
    } while (true);
}

template <class T>
void display(vector <T> &ar){
    for(auto i = ar.begin(); i != ar.end(); i++){
        cout << *i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;
}
int main() {
    vector <int> X {6,1,7,1,3,2,6723,4,6,1};
    X.reserve(X.size() * 2);
    display <int>(X);
    isort <int>(X);
    display <int>(X);
}
```

Comment: `for(auto i = ar.end() - 2; i >= ar.begin(); --i)` invoked undefined behaviour. You can't decrement `ar.begin()`.

Comment: Added check on elements number.

Comment: The number of elements is not *the* problem. The problem is that you decrement `i` when `i` is already equal to `ar.begin()`. That's why we have [reverse iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) as a separate concept.

Comment: It doesn't help. Take a look yourself: https://godbolt.org/z/xxv4Pzqsa

Comment: Decrementing `begin()` is undefined behaviour by the standard. If code appears to work in some implementation, it doesn't mean that that code is correct. "Appears to work" is one possible outcome of UB.

Comment: Plz take a look